# Using " this" in java

Tags: java, methods, this, uppercase

I have been given a code and need to "fill in the blanks", for one part of the problem I need to write a method that will check that a string has only letters from the alphabet ( no commas or periods or numbers) and then if there are upper case letters, convert them to lower case.

I think I understand how to write this, however this is part of the code that is given

```
public Message (String m){
    message = m;
    lengthOfMessage = m.length();
    this.makeValid();
```

The method I have to write is the makeValid one, but I'm not sure how to use the `this.makeValid` and how to write the code if the method doesn't take a string as the argument?

Note: I understand now that I can use `message` and `lengthOfmessage` but i am still trying to wrap my head around it.
would this code make sense and make proper use of the `this`

```
public void makeValid(){
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfMessage ; i++ ) {
        char mchar = message.charAt(i);
        if (64 <= mchar && mchar<= 90) {
            mchar = (char)((mchar + 32));
            builder.append(mChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `message` and `lengthOfMessage` seem to be members of the class. That's why you don't need to pass these values as parameters to the method. This style of programming can be considered bad BTW.

Comment: You can access `message` and `lengthOfMessage`, so you don't need the `m` as a parameter. Of course it would be a lot cleaner with a parameter, but hey, tasks are tasks.

Comment: 'this' is a reference to the current Message object; 'makeValid()' is a method of the Message class. The method can access the class members, like 'message' and 'lengthOfMessage', so they don't need to be supplied as arguments.

Comment: In this case, `this` doesn't do anything and can be removed.